# Can you set the category of an ad that is displayed with the android sdk?

Tags: android, mobile, admob, native, ads

If I have a page on my android app which is related to cars, can I customise the ads shown so that only ads about cars appear?

I have set ads by using Google's AdMob. How far can I customise the ads that appear? Could I provide specific keywords like "cricket" or "backpacks"?

I want the ad to be an AdMob native ad.

I would need the same for an iOS app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Native ads are only given to selected developers/companies who make more money for Google, and I don't think there is certain criteria that is mentioned anywhere to be eligible to get those.

As the page for [Native Ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/start) here says:

> Note: Native Ads Advanced is currently released to a limited set of
>   publishers. If you're interested in participating, reach out to your
>   account manager to discuss the possibility.

If you absolutely want the Native Ads into your app, you can use Facebook Ads platform for monetization as they offer Native Ads without any special requirements.

You can select only ads related to car by disabling all the other ads from your admob panel. You can disable the other ads by going into **"Blocking Controls"** section of your app. But it'd not be good move as Google caters ads based on what user needs, if your app is about car, showing only ads related to cars "MIGHT" benefit you, but it'd drastically reduce your fill rate which will affect your revenue very very much.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. I have multiple pages which can be related to anything (cars, sports, etc.) that the user creates, so I would need to set the category of the ads programmatically. I want to put user experience over revenue, so I think I'll search for something else other than Google.

Comment: limiting your ads is never an option. If you reduce your fill rate, you're reducing your revenue.